# Magento 2 - sorting order of products in a widget block

Tags: magento2, sorting, widget

I created a **block** and a **widget** in the admin panel to show products that fit some criteria(in a **specified category**) on **home page**.

When I finished the setting, I found that the **sorting order** of the products showing on the homepage did not match with the **sorting order** assigned in the **category**.

How can I make the products show in the correct order?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?